# iron-collapse opened=false not collapsing when bound with Boolean property of object

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an array of objects which has a field to indicate whether its properties should be displayed:

```
[{
  state: true
},
{
  state: false
},
{
  state: false
}]
```

And I use Polymer iron-collapse's "opened" field to bind with state in order to collapse it. 
This works in Polymer 0.5, but it fails in 1.0. Also, it works if I directly pass a boolean property - just not with an object.

When I say "doesn't work", I mean that the collapsing doesn't happen.

What did I fail to migrate properly? Or is this a bug in iron-collapse?

---

## This Works:

### (Using an Array of Boolean)

**demo.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="iron-collapse-demo.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iron-collapse-demo states='[ true, false, false ]'></iron-collapse-demo>
  </body>
</html>
```

**iron-collapse-demo.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <dom-module id="iron-collapse-demo">
      <style>
      </style>
      <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{states}}">
          <span on-tap="collapseToggle"><+></span>
          <iron-collapse opened="{{item}}">
            <div>Hello collapse!</div>
          </iron-collapse>
        </template>
      </template>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
  <script src="iron-collapse-demo.html.0.js"></script>
</html>
```

**iron-collapse-demo.html.0.js:**

```
  Polymer({
    'is': 'iron-collapse-demo',
    'properties': {
      'states': Array
    },
    'ready': function() {

    },
    'collapseToggle': function(event, detail, sender) {
      event.model.item = !event.model.item;
    },
  });
```

---

## This doesn't work:

### (Using an Array of Object with a Boolean property)

**demo.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="iron-collapse-demo.html">
</head>
  <body>
    <iron-collapse-demo nums='[ {"state": true}, {"state": false}, {"state": false} ]'></iron-collapse-demo>
  </body>
</html>
```

**iron-collapse-demo.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <dom-module id="iron-collapse-demo">
      <style>
      </style>
      <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{nums}}">
          <span on-tap="collapseToggle"><+></span>
          <iron-collapse opened="{{item.state}}">
            <div>Hello collapse!</div>
          </iron-collapse>
        </template>
      </template>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
  <script src="iron-collapse-demo.html.0.js"></script>
</html>
```

**iron-collapse-demo.html.0.js:**

```
  Polymer({
    'is': 'iron-collapse-demo',
    'properties': {
      'nums': Array
    },
    'ready': function() {

    },
    'collapseToggle': function(event, detail, sender) {
      var num = event.model.item;
      num.state = !num.state;
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hack/workaround, though I'm not convinced this should be the only way that works..

I wrapped the ***span*** and ***iron-collapse*** inside a div so that I can use a querySelector and toggle() the collapse.

**iron-collapse-demo.html:**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{nums}}">
  <div>
    <span on-tap="collapseToggle"><+></span>
    <iron-collapse opened="{{item.state}}">
      <div>Hello collapse!</div>
    </iron-collapse>
  </div>
</template>
```

**iron-collapse-demo.html.0.js:**

new collapseToggle:

```
'collapseToggle': function(event, detail, sender) {
    // event.model.item.state = !event.model.item.state;
    event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector('iron-collapse').toggle();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<iron-collapse horizontal opened$="[[item.state]]">
  ...
</iron-collapse>
```

HTML booleans are true when the attribute is present, not if the value of the attribute is true. Binding the attribute instead of value means Polymer outputs the attribute name when `true` but nothing for false.